# How can I change the last character of x lines?

Tags: regex, end-of-line

I have a text with 500 lines, I want to take the last character of every **10 lines** and change it to a semicolon symbol without changing the content of the rest of the lines. What you should do is change 50 lines and add to all of them; at the end changing the last character (whatever it is) for a **semicolon**.

**Example:**

```
line1'
line2{
line3+
line4´
```

If I apply the logic that I have proposed above, for every second line it should look like this:

```
line1'
line2;
line3+
line4;
```

I want to do it only using `Regex`, without programming languages or similar.

**My Regex:**

```
^(.*\r?\n){9}(.*)(.)$
```

Comment: Like this? `^((?:.*\r?\n){9}.*).$` and then replace with `$1;` https://regex101.com/r/IOTuJH/1

Comment: Who is you in: "What you should do is ..." ??

Comment: @Luuk, _Plato_?

Answer (score 0):

In your pattern you have 3 capture groups, where you can also just use 1 capture group. But what you should not do is repeat the capture group itself, as you would then only capture the value of the last iteration.

Using `^(.*\r?\n){9}` you would then only capture the 9th line, and you would lose the first 8 lines when you only use the capture groups in the replacement.

You can use a single capture group, and within that group you can match 9 lines ending on a newline and then then 10th line.

After the capture group you can match a single character. Note that the `.` matches any character, and it will not match if the 10th line is empty.

```
^((?:.*\r?\n){9}.*).$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IOTuJH/1)

In the replacement use group 1 followed by a semicolon often denoted as `$1;` or `\1;`

Comment: @AztecCodes No it is not, see https://regex101.com/r/7g7ccR/1